# Product count mismatch in magento default product export

Tags: magento-1.9, product, magento-community, export

I have a doubt when i check product count in `catalog -> manage product section` it showing some count ex: "Total 28000 records found" But when i export that all products in `System -> import/export -> Exports sections` i got an 26800 product only some products are gone.

I have a confident this related core functions would not change any time.
So please give me your idea regarding what are the possibility available to happened this issues.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure, but it has probably something to do with status or visibility of product. Please check the values of 'status' or visibility attributes for products not in the export file.